# Why do I get a MySQL syntax error even though the cell updates correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

The **error** thrown:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

The relevant **code**:

```
$update = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $update);
// $update = '10'; $id = '4'
$sql = "UPDATE tasks SET `shortDesc` = '".$update."' WHERE `id`=".$id;
if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql) === TRUE) {
    echo 1;
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($connection);
}
```

I was not able to locate any similar error on the forum that would be of help.
Why is it working but throws an error?

Comment: What is the value of `$id`? If that isn't an integer and is a string, then there's your problem.

Comment: And what is the value of $update ?

Comment: But the row is updated correctly ?

Comment: echo or var_dump the `$sql` part and show us what comes of it.

Comment: Another possible explanation may lie in what you're not showing us; for instance, having 2x instances of `mysqli_query()`; I've seen that happen before. What you posted for code will not throw that error, unless your rows aren't `int`.

Comment: and also add the rest of the error message

Comment: Provide the raw mysql query. Without it the question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted should not cause an error, given, that the parameter `$id` is never empty. Actually looking at your error message and your query, this could be the only error produced, because if both variables are empty, you will have:

```
UPDATE tasks SET `shortDesc` = '' WHERE `id`=
```

This will fail, because there is no value for id. Since MySQL has not problem with numbers in quotes, this should eliminate the error message:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tasks SET `shortDesc` = '".$update."' WHERE `id`='".$id."'";
```

You can optimize this for better reading:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tasks SET `shortDesc` = '$update' WHERE `id`='$id'";
```

Now if the variables are empty the query still does not become invalid.

Since this is or was the only source of error in your code, i reckon something is missing in your listing, or your code was called twice with missing parameters?

For quality assurance you should check $update and $id for validity before using them anyhow. at least make sure they are not empty, since then you can spare the call.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the code was called twice (once pressing enter and automatically on the focusout event. One of those times the parameter was removed and the query hit a dead end.

Comment: @daniel Which in theory, I was right about [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322238/why-do-i-get-a-mysql-syntax-error-even-though-the-cell-updates-correctly#comment46835788_29322238) I left. Posting relevant code always helps us figure out the exact cause.

Comment: @fred: sometimes it is just the shadow of the absent... this shadow here, was the only possible error cause :)